# Implement restendpoints in server c#

Tags: c#, rest

I'm currently developing a simple embedded rest server with c#. Runs as Windows Service)

My problem is that i don't know how to implement the endpoints.

Would it be a good approach to make a class and then all endpoint classes inherit from this one. 
At the start of the server i'll check all mehtods with reflection and take them with the right attributes (custom attributes for endpoint definition) and register them to the restmanager class. So i know all enpoints and the right mehtods of them.

Can u show me a better approach or is it ok?